# Find elements by offset position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

Is there a simple method to fetch all elements at a specific offset position (by using jQuery)? Or do I have to check the offset of each element in the DOM?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint).

Comment: wow that's pretty cool.  Does it work in old IE versions? (well I guess I could just check ...)

Comment: Good, I didn't know about it..But it returns just 1 element.. What if there are 2 elems in the same position?

Comment: I'm guessing that it'll basically tell you what the target element would be if there were a mouse click at precisely that location.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only method would be to fetch all the elements. There are no other ways to retrieve a set of elements that are in a particular position

Comment: Yeah now I now that exists that document.elementfrompoint :) Ty! but what does it return if 2 sibling elements are in the same position?

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery has a method, then it'll loop through all elements and check. There isn't another logical way to do it.

As far as I know, jQuery doesn't, so do loop through the Elements; you can use `$().each(function());`